# Maven: how to get a war package with resources copied in WEB-INF?

Tags: maven, war

when I create a war package with maven, files and directories under the directory "src/main/resources" are copied in /WEB-INF/classes instead of /WEB-INF. How can I get them copied in /WEB-INF?

thanks,
rand

UPDATE:
in my pom now I use this:

```
<plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.3</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-resources</id>
                    <!-- here the phase you need -->
                    <phase>war</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>myapp/target/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                        <resources>
                            <resource>
                                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
                                <filtering>true</filtering>
                            </resource>
                        </resources>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

and I launch mvn with:

> mvn -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package resources:copy-resources

but I got:

```
[INFO] One or more required plugin parameters are invalid/missing for 'resources:copy-resources'

[0] Inside the definition for plugin 'maven-resources-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <outputDirectory>VALUE</outputDirectory>
</configuration>.

[1] Inside the definition for plugin 'maven-resources-plugin' specify the following:

<configuration>
  ...
  <resources>VALUE</resources>
</configuration>.
```

I'm using maven 2.2 and the snippet basically is the same of the documentation
any idea?

Comment: don't run the `resources:copy-resources` goal, it's automatically included in phase `copy-resources` (down there in my answer)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

either configure the `outputDirectory` parameter of `resources:resources` plugin, or put your files under `src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/` directory.
[resource plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/resources-mojo.html)

**EDIT:**

This configuration is working for me:

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>default-copy-resources</id>
        <phase>process-resources</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>copy-resources</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <overwrite>true</overwrite>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF/</outputDirectory>
          <resources>
            <resource>
              <directory>${project.basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
          </resources>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
```

you can run a phase in the form `somePhase` or a goal `somePlugin:someGoal`. The phase invocations will invoke all plugins goals hooked on phases in interval [validate,phase] in order, so there's no need to explicitly call them.

Comment: One can use as well the `${project.build.finalName}` instead of `${project.artifactId}-${project.version}` to get the name of the artifact.

Answer (score 28):

Web resources are not the same as java resources, which should be placed in the classpath. Web resources are processed via the war plugin and should be placed into `src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\`.  In this case, it will work automatically without any additional configuration in the pom.xml

Comment: But, how to deal with `java resource`, if it is not auto deployed to its required place?

Comment: @Eddy If it is not deployed into the "required place", most probably it means you put it in the wrong place of a source code. Give more details.

Comment: You are right! In this case: when using maven and run `mvn clean`. then maven will not redeploy it for me when put resources under `src/main/java` instead of `src/main/resources`. I'm using eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

This configuration is working add plugin pom.xml

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>${jdk.version}</source>
        <target>${jdk.version}</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>

    <configuration>

        <webResources>
              <!--copy resource file location-->
            <resource>
                <directory>${project.build.directory}/classes</directory>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
        <!--location for add file-->
        <webappDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}</webappDirectory>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Using maven [*WAR Plug*](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html) to copy any web resources is the bast way.