# Primefaces - No taglibrary exists - configurated pom.xml

Tags: xml, eclipse, maven, jsf, primefaces

i got the error

```
Warning: This page calls for XML namespace http://primefaces.prime.com.tr/ui declared with prefix p but no taglibrary exists for that namespace
```

My question is similar to this question:
[Link to Questtion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18748457/xml-namespace-http-primefaces-org-ui-showing-warning-that-no-taglibrary-exists)

i include in the pom.xml file

```
  <repositories>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>
    </repositories>

...
<dependencyManagement>
...
   <dependency>
     <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
     <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
     <version>3.5</version>
   </dependency>
</dependencyManagement>
```

The xhtml Page importData looks like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:head><title>Test</title></h:head>
<h:body>
  <p:panel header="Test" toggleable="true">
    <h:outputText value="Hallo, hier spricht PrimeFaces!"/>
  </p:panel>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I used Tomcat 7, Eclipse Kepler and Maven. Any idea?

Update:
If i write the primefaces dependendcy in the `<dependencies>` i get the error

```
Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character
```

Eclipse write in the konsole:

```
Apr 09, 2014 10:19:23 AM com.sun.faces.config.AnnotationScanner processClassList
Schwerwiegend: Unable to load annotated class: WEB-INF.classes. [...], reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: [...] (wrong name: [...])

Apr 09, 2014 10:19:24 AM com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy handleRenderException
Schwerwiegend: Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContext.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContextFacade.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResourcePaths(ExternalContextImpl.java:520)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.WebappResourceHelper.findLibrary(WebappResourceHelper.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findLibrary(ResourceManager.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getResourceInfo(ResourceManager.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:181)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.createResource(PrimeResourceHandler.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeTheme(HeadRenderer.java:115)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)

Apr 09, 2014 10:19:24 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: JSF1073: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException erfasst während Verarbeitung von RENDER_RESPONSE 6 : UIComponent-ClientId=, Message=Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character
Apr 09, 2014 10:19:24 AM com.sun.faces.context.ExceptionHandlerImpl log
1100: Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContext.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContextFacade.getResourcePaths(ApplicationContextFacade.java:181)
    at com.sun.faces.context.ExternalContextImpl.getResourcePaths(ExternalContextImpl.java:520)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.WebappResourceHelper.findLibrary(WebappResourceHelper.java:190)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findLibrary(ResourceManager.java:458)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.getResourceInfo(ResourceManager.java:286)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.doLookup(ResourceManager.java:280)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:214)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceManager.findResource(ResourceManager.java:180)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:201)
    at com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl.createResource(ResourceHandlerImpl.java:181)
    at javax.faces.application.ResourceHandlerWrapper.createResource(ResourceHandlerWrapper.java:112)
    at org.primefaces.application.PrimeResourceHandler.createResource(PrimeResourceHandler.java:57)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeTheme(HeadRenderer.java:115)
    at org.primefaces.renderkit.HeadRenderer.encodeBegin(HeadRenderer.java:72)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeBegin(UIComponentBase.java:864)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1894)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1899)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:451)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:131)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:120)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:219)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:647)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:502)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:953)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1023)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
```

Upadte:
I have also the error if i placed primefaces in the `<dependency>` and `<dependencyManagement>`

Update:
I think i know the resolution. The Taglibary from maven disappear in the Web Resources -> Tag Libaries Folder. But i added the taglibary like below.

Here is the complete pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                        http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <!-- The Basics -->
  <groupId>AssetDB</groupId>
  <artifactId>AssetDB</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <!-- Build Settings -->
    <build>
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>                   
        </plugins>
    </build>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>2.11.3</version>
      </dependency>

     <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
     </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-api</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.myfaces.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>myfaces-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.1.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
      </dependencies>

   <repositories>
        <repository>  
            <id>prime-repo</id>  
            <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
            <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
            <layout>default</layout>  
        </repository>
  </repositories>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you try setting the theme manually in your `<dependencies>`.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
    <artifactId>aristo</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

or try another theme like `bootstrap`

Comment: If i write this depedency i get the error i reconfigure my pom.xml.

Comment: @marius0114 are you having the same error when using this `<dependency>` ? and did you try a maven build with `clean install -X -e` ?

Comment: If i write it in dependencyManagement i get no error. How must i write clean install -X -e in the maven build from eclipse?

Comment: From the menu Run > Run Configurations... > Maven Build > New Launch Configuration (a paper plus icon on the top left of the left list).
In your Base Directory, set your project.
in Goals, set `clean install -X -e`
Hit Run when done.

Comment: The good answer ist i get the taglib. Thanks for this. The bad answer is i can add aristo as dependency. I get the error `Missing artifact org.primefaces.themes:aristo:jar:1.0.10` And if i don'r write the depency i the pom.xml i get the old error : `Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character`

Comment: If i write the primefaces dependendy in the pedendendyManagement i lost the taglib. So i must add Primefaces in the dependency.

Comment: oh my bad, `aristo` theme is at its `1.0.1`, so just change the version to `<version>1.0.1</version>`.
And don't forget to set:
`<context-param>  
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>  
    <param-value>aristo</param-value>  
</context-param>`
Check this http://repository.primefaces.org/org/primefaces/themes/ for the full list of themes.

Comment: I get the same error. But with the build goals from you i have updated my pom.xml see below. I delete all depedencyManagements and add them to dependency.

Comment: have you tried `<artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>` with `<version>1.0.10</version>`, it's a different theme, but just for testing now.

Comment: Why is the `org.primefaces.themes` not part of depedency primefaces-4.0 jar?. I looked at the Maven Dependencies Libary and the primefaces-4.0 jar. But where is no package with the name `org.primefaces.themes`.

Comment: No. The <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId> with <version>1.0.10</version> gets no solution. The same error Path./WEB-INF/...

Comment: No `org.primefaces.themes` is a different `<dependency>` from `org.primefaces`, you should have both.
And can you check your target folder for the `bootstrap-1.0.10.jar` after the clean install.

Comment: I did that. But this doesn't resolved the problem. But i think i found the Problem. The path from aristo are: `META-INF/resouces/primefaces-aristo`. bootstrap has the path : `META-INF/resouces/primefaces-bootstrap`. The error said he didn't find the path `WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo`

Answer (score 0):

try change your declare tab lib for:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. But it doesn't help. Other idea?

Comment: Try change the tag </dependencyManagement> for the <dependencies> and </dependencies>

Comment: This is a good point. But i get the Error `Path ./WEB-INF/resources/primefaces-aristo does not start with a "/" character` on the first page. This page have no primefaces tags. The primefaces tags are in another page.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.
I had written in the web.xml. Now i delete his.

```
 <context-param>
  <param-name>javax.faces.WEBAPP_RESOURCES_DIRECTORY</param-name>
  <param-value>./WEB-INF/resources</param-value>
 </context-param>
```

The Web-App have look in this folder to find the primefaces resources.
I don't need the depedency aristo or bootstrap. Thanks for all your help.

The Maven-build `clean install -X -e` helps me to delete the `<depedendyManagement>`. So thanks for this answer.

Comment: This shouldn't be the case to write this manually, check your configurations again, or check this question that can be helpful in your case as you both have `war` packaging http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760827/maven-how-to-get-a-war-package-with-resources-copied-in-web-inf

Comment: i don't understand my. I delete this context-param. I had written this a time ago in the web.xml.