# Maven: how to copy resources into WAR?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, ant

I have an Eclipse webapp project that I am trying to migrate from Ant build to Maven build. I have a lot of non-Java files in my `src/` folder, for example `log4j2.xml`, `ehcache.xml`, some `.properties` localization files etc.

When I run `war:war` target on this project, the resulting WAR file contains only the `.class` files in the `WEB-INF/classes` folder, all the non-Java files are missing. In Ant I did this:

```
<target name="copy-resources" depends="compile">
  <copy todir="${build}">
    <fileset dir="${src}">
      <exclude name="**/*.java"/>
    </fileset>
  </copy>
</target>
```

How do I achieve the same thing in Maven? I suspect I should be using the `resources` folder, but right now I am trying to migrate with as little changes to the original codebase as possible...

Comment: please take a look at this:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4760827/maven-how-to-get-a-war-package-with-resources-copied-in-web-inf

Comment: Resources belong in `src/main/resources`.

They will be packaged automatically.

You will be better off putting them where they belong than twisting Maven around to fit a non-Maven project structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can access these files from resources folder. I hope this 
[link](http://devblog.virtage.com/2013/07/how-to-get-file-resource-from-maven-srctestresources-folder-in-junit-test/) helps.

You can also specify the folder, if it is not the default resources folder, in the pom.xml.  See
[Specifying resource directories](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/resource-directory.html).

For example, if your folder has these files in src/my-resources, then you need to add this to the pom.xml, and then you would be able access it in code.

```
   <resources>
     <resource>
       <directory>src/my-resources</directory>
     </resource>
   </resources>
```